# MVC3 session-scope variable to hold file uploads?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I'd like to hold a collection of uploaded files for a user (where there might be multiple requests for each file, or even multiple requests per-file for chunking), but I'm struggling to find the appropriate scope. Once they're done, another request will say so, and the collection will dump its data to physical files and a DB entry and empty itself.

Ben here: http://buildstarted.com/2011/07/17/asp-net-mvc-3-file-uploads-using-the-fileapi/ uses a static collection, but that would be inappropriate for multiple users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the files somewhere semi-permanent. Session could be reset along with the app domain, so you can't rely on it 100%.

Just have a separate file/db location or flag which lets you know the whole set of files is not completed.

Comment: Ok, and then do the quick "file exists" lookup from a dictionary keyed to a userID cookie or something?